# How to display error (text/html) response to an AJAX/getJSON request?

Tags: javascript, ajax, error-handling

My situation is, I'm developing a little web app where the server provides dynamic JSON responses.  The server is built on cherrypy.  Sometimes, there is a bug in the code creating the JSON data, which throws, and cherrypy catches it and serves back a 500-error with a full HTML page detailing the exception.  (That is, the response has everything: `<!doctype..><html><head>...</head><body>...</body></html>`)
But because the request is AJAX, it doesn't get displayed.

I can intercept this error easily enough, and look at it in the dev tools; but what I'd like to do (to ease debugging) is open a new page (as if user had followed a link) and display that response in the browser.  I tried

```
window.open('', '_self');
$(document).html(jqXHR.responseText);
```

but I just get a blank page.  I suppose I could store the error text and serve it up in a second request to the server, but is there a cleaner way?

---

To follow up, the final code that worked was this:

```
.error(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    $(window).bind('unload', function() { document.write(jqXHR.responseText); } );
    var win = window.open('', '_self');
    return false;
});
```

Not sure if that final `return false` is necessary but it seems good form.

---

Following up again: the above code worked reliably in Opera.  I thought I had seen it working in Webkit as well, but I started noticing that it wasn't; and on further testing, it wasn't working for Firefox either.

What I found that worked in all three platforms was this:

```
document.open('text/html', true);
document.write(jqXHR.responseText);
document.close();
```

Don't have to open another window or bind events; just re-open the document and stuff the text in there.

---

Well, here I am again.  The above technique either stopped working or I was tripping when I said it ever worked at all.  Chrome, in particular, doesn't seem to have `document.open` defined.

But! I just found a nifty technique that seems to work everywhere:

```
errtext = 'data:text/html;base64,' + window.btoa(jqXHR.responseText);
window.open(errtext, '_self');
```

This simply converts the response into a fully self-contained `data:` URL and opens it in the window.

Comment: are you using any specific libraries?

Comment: I'm using jQuery, but I'd think the technique I want could be done with any lib or even native JS.

Comment: +1 for the research.  Your document open/write/close solution works in IE8 (though the others don't).  I'm sure I've got a ways to go when I look at other browsers--I'm sure I'll be back here soon.  I can't believe something so basic is so difficult, so complicated, and so undocumented.

Comment: +1 for "tripping"...I know the feeling!  Yeah, I'm lost.  When I execute my ajax call locally the error callback gives me my error.  When deployed, the response contains the entire document.  I'm not trying to do anything clever.  I just want to get the error message. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var win = window.open('', '_self');
win.document.getElementsByTagName('Body')[0].innerText = jqXHR.responseText;
```

Comment: That doesn't work (still just see a blank page).  I added a clarification in the example: the data returned is everything, not just a '<body>' tag.

Comment: Try:    win.document.writeln(jqXHR.responseText);

Comment: That's close! The error is written into the page, but then another blank page opens over the displayed error message.  When I back-button, I can see the error.  The JS console shows a weird error stack that doesn't look directly related, but is sourced in jQuery's request.complete() function.

Comment: You may have to listen/attach to the unload event and do the document.writeln in the handler

Comment: Good call.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: FYI, I had to back out your solution; see the question for details.